# Tricky combination of two lists using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I hope somebody will be able to guide me in right direction here...

```
public class SubmissionLog
{  
    public int PKId {get;set;}  
    public int SubmissionId {get;set;}  
    public DateTime Created {get;set;}   
    public int StatusId {get;set;}
}
```

And this is the data:

```
1, 123, '1/24/2013 01:00:00', 1  
2, 456, '1/24/2013 01:30:00', 1  
3, 123, '1/25/2013 21:00:00', 2  
4, 456, '1/25/2013 21:30:00', 2  
5, 123, '2/25/2013 22:00:00', 1  
6, 123, '2/26/2013 21:00:00', 2  
7, 123, '2/16/2013 21:30:00', 1
```

What I am trying to is following:
I'd like to know the the average time span from StatusId 1 to StatusId 2 on a given day.

So, let's say date is 2/26/2013, then what I thought would make sense if first get the list like this:

```
var endlingList = (from sl in db.SubmissionLogs  
    where (DateTime.Now.AddDays(days).Date == sl.Created.Date) // days = passed number of days to make it 2/26/2013  
    && (sl.StatusId == 2)  
    select sl).ToList();

var endingLookup = endlingList.ToLookup(a => a.SubmissionId, a => a.Created); // thought of using lookup because Dictionary doesn't allow duplicates
```

After that I thought I'd figure out starting points

```
var startingList = (from sl in db.SubmissionLogs  
where endingList.Select(a => a.SubmissionId).ToArray().Contains(sl.QuoteId)  
&& sl.StatusId == 1
select sl).ToList();
```

And then what I did was following:

```
var revisedList = endingLookup.Select(a =>
new SubmissionInterval {
    SubmissionId = a.Key,
    EndDateTime = endingLookup[a.Key].FirstOrDefault(), //This is where the problem is. This will only grab the first occurance.
    StartDateTime = startLookup[a.Key].FirstOrDefault() //This is where the problem is. This will only grab the first occurance.
});
```

And then what I do to get average is following (again, this will only include the initial or first ocurances of status 1 and status 2 of some submission id Submission Log):

```
return revisedList.Count() > 0 ? revisedList.Select(a=> a.EndDateTime.Subtract(a.StartDateTime).TotalHours).Average() : 0;
```

So, I hope somebody will understand what my problem here is first of all... To re-cap, I want to get timespan between each status 1 and 2. I pass the date in, and then I have to look up 2's as that ensures me that I will find 1's. If I went the other way around and looked for 1's, then 2's may not exist (don't want that anyway).

At the end I wanna be able to average stuff out...
So let's say if some submission first went from 1 to 2 in a time span of 5h (the code that I left, will get me up to this point), then let's say it got reassigned to 1 and then it went back to 2 in a new time span of 6h, I wanna be able to get both and do the average, so (5+6)/2.

Thanks

Comment: iboros, where `QuoteId` is coming from? The SubmissionLog class?

Comment: I'm sorry but all of that does not make sense. Can you explain at a higher level what you want to do? What does it mean to get the "average time span from StatusId 1 to StatusId 2 on a given day?"

Comment: Do you mean that you want the average for all days previous up to a given day? That is, for a given SubmissionID, find the average of all times that it has transitioned between StatusID 1 & 2 up to that day?

Comment: I know that I perhaps didn't do the best job possible on writing out the question, however, Phil understood what I was trying to achieve.
His answer below helped me out. If anyone wants, I can edit the question and share the code. I basically dropped everything that I was doing up where and ended up proceeding by using sub-query as Phil suggested and explained. Thanks everyone for involvement though. For a 1000000th time SO didn't disappoint. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  Does thishelp

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<SubmissionLog>
    {
        new SubmissionLog(1, 123, "1/24/2013 01:00:00", 1),
        new SubmissionLog(2, 456, "1/24/2013 01:30:00", 1),
        new SubmissionLog(3, 123, "1/25/2013 21:00:00", 2),
        new SubmissionLog(4, 456, "1/25/2013 21:30:00", 2),
        new SubmissionLog(5, 123, "2/25/2013 22:00:00", 1),
        new SubmissionLog(6, 123, "2/26/2013 21:00:00", 2),
        new SubmissionLog(7, 123, "2/16/2013 21:30:00", 1),
    };

    // split out status 1 and 2
    var s1s = list.Where (l => l.StatusId == 1).OrderBy (l => l.Created);
    var s2s = list.Where (l => l.StatusId == 2).OrderBy (l => l.Created);

    // use a sub-query to get the first s2 after each s1
    var q = s1s.Select (s1 => new 
        {
            s1, 
            s2 = s2s.FirstOrDefault (s2 => 
                s1.SubmissionId == s2.SubmissionId &&
                s2.Created >= s1.Created    
            )
        }
    ).Where (s => s.s1.PKId < s.s2.PKId && s.s2 != null);

        // extract the info we need 
        // note that TotalSecond is ok in Linq to Object but you'll 
        // probably need to use SqlFunctions or equivalent if this is to 
        // run against a DB.
    var q1 = q.Select (x => new 
        {
            Start=x.s1.Created,
            End=x.s2.Created,
            SubmissionId=x.s1.SubmissionId, 
            Seconds=(x.s2.Created - x.s1.Created).TotalSeconds
        }
    );

        // group by submissionId and average the time
    var q2 = q1.GroupBy (x => x.SubmissionId).Select (x => new {
        x.Key, 
        Count=x.Count (),
        Start=x.Min (y => y.Start),
        End=x.Max (y => y.End),
        Average=x.Average (y => y.Seconds)});
}

public class SubmissionLog
{  
    public SubmissionLog(int id, int submissionId, string date, int statusId)
    {
        PKId = id;
        SubmissionId = submissionId;
        Created = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
        StatusId = statusId;
    }
    public int PKId {get;set;}  
    public int SubmissionId {get;set;}  
    public DateTime Created {get;set;}   
    public int StatusId {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phil, let me try to using this approach.

Comment: Phil, you sir are a genius! :)